# Linux kernel version

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

When I get my kernel version (by ***uname -r*** command) terminal prints ***3.2.6***, but on [kernel.org](https://www.kernel.org) writes, that "latest stable version 3.14.2", so I don't understand, is it latest version, or it is only *stable* latest version?

Comment: This means your kernel is outdated. You can upgrade to a newer kernel. However, in most cases you should use one of the kernels your distribution is offering and let the package manager take care of kernel upgrades.

Comment: The kernel version installed on your system, depends on your Linux distribution, and how long time ago it was updated.

Comment: Maybe you are comparing it wrongly. The `3.` is the same, but `2 < 14`, so you version is older than the one announced in kernel.org. The third number doesn't matter unless the other two are the same.

Comment: @rodrigo: thank you, I think that it is decimal fraction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The software version announced on a website (in this case the linux kernel from kernel.org), is not automatically the one you have installed on your system.